# Get ContentType name with select fields

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I have a problem with getting the ContentType name for a item.

when i use

```
http://sp2013dev/sites/mms/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List')/items(1)/?$expand=ContentType
```

I get as response all Fields from the ContentType, which is so far not bad,
but if I use also `select` in the query the ContentType Fields are not included in the results it only returns

**Result:**

```
 ContentType: {
__deferred: {
uri: "http://site/_api/Web/Lists(guid'b911f75b-1988-4f44-bd88-39ab510562a4')/Items(1)/ContentType"
}-
}
```

**Query:**

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List')/items(1)/?$select=Id,Title,ContentType&$expand=ContentType
```

And the second problem is that when I use `?$expand=ContentType/Name` (I only need the name of the ContentType) it is ignored completely and I get all Fields from the ContentType

**Edit:**

After trying

> /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('')/items()/?$select=Id,FileRef,ContentType/Id,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType

as recommend by Vadim i get the following response

```
{
  d: {
      __metadata: {
           id: "4b62e4e7-a023-4992-b689-e9cf49f3ef86"
           uri: "<url>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'b911f75b-1988-4f44-bd88-39ab510562a4')/Items(1)"
           etag: ""3""
           type: "SP.Data.AgendaElementsUsedListItem"
     }
     ContentType: {
           __deferred: {
               uri: "<url>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'b911f75b-1988-4f44-bd88-39ab510562a4')/Items(1)/ContentType"
           }
     }
     Id: 1
     ID: 1
     FileRef: "/sites/mms/Lists/AgendaElementsUsed/1_.000"
     }
}
```

Comment: How incredibly odd. According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx) you should be able to use the layout you have (.../Items(1)?$select=ContentType/Description&$expand=ContentType/Description). I did a quick test and this works: `$select=*&$expand=ContentType` (but doesn't help of course), as well does `...Items(1)/ContentType/Description` and `.../Items(1)/ContentType?$select=Description`.

Comment: Yeah these are working at least to get the name of the contentype `.../Items(1)/ContentType?$select=Description` but then I'am missing some custom fields from the listitem (id,title,...)

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to think this might be a SharePoint bug actually. ContentType is a bit special, but it should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `$expand` operator specifies which projected fields from a joined list are returned, the REST query:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<List Title>')/items(<Item Id>)/?$expand=ContentType
```

returns list item entity with content type entity.

In order to return the specific item properties along with Content Type properties, you should use `$select` and `$expand` operators as demonstrated below:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<List Title>')/items(<Item Id>)/?$select=Id,FileRef,ContentType/Id,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType
```

[image]

Comment: This actually works for you? It does not for me, and I have a very strong feeling it does not for OP either

Comment: works for me, at least in SharePoint Online

Comment: I tried on __15.0.4569.1000__. Neither any of the approaches above, or copied directly from your answer, either with direct opening in browser or with `application/json;odata=verbose` (as I think is what you are using)

Comment: It is also not working for me on Premise on Version `15.0.4481.1005` you can see my edit for the response I got

Comment: So I did a quick check against SharePoint Online there indeed it is working... So it is a bug in the SharePoint on Premise versions we are using I think ? Could not update to Service Pack 1 because it is currently retracted to have a look if it is fixed there

Comment: Mark, since i don't have access to On-Premise currently, cant confirm it, but it seems you are right that this is a bug..

Comment: Ok damn, then I have to wait till SP1 will be out again. I think there will be the fix for this in it. So I will mark this as answer, because I think it will be fixed than in On Premise thanks guys

Answer (score 16):

Add ContentTypeId to your select. In an on premise SP 2013 environment I found this is an important key. To return the ContentType Name, it is not enough to expand the content type. You also have to include ContentTypeId in the select.
In other words, this will not achieve the desired result:

```
?$select=Id,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType
```

However, this will:

```
?$select=Id,ContentTypeId,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I'm on 2013.

Comment: Yes indeed, this does seem to be the trick for SharePoint on premises. Probably should be the accepted answer too.